# substitute field name in linq where clause by combo text

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a combo with 6 text `NA,PO,FA,GO,VG,EX` and I want to do a Linq query upon the selected value in this combo used as field in the where clause. for example:

```
'if "NA" is selected :
Dim query = from t in db.table where t.NA > 0 Select t
'If "PO" is selected :
Dim query = from t in db.table where t.PO > 0 select t
```

etc...

How to do this in elegant way without writing 6 if statement or using "Select case"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use reflection to get the `PropertyInfo` based on the selected string.  Then use that in your LINQ query.  Going to the database might make it sad, though... I'm not sure without trying it.  You'd use the `PropertyInfo` in your LINQ query like this:

```
Dim selectedPropertyInfo = db.table.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "NA")

Dim query = from t in db.table
            where selectedPropertyInfo.GetValue(t, null) > 0
            select t;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your solution, neither I had found an example of how to use PropertyInfo.GetValue to substitute string field name. Can you guide me to link ?

Comment: I've added a line to show you how to get the `PropertyInfo`.  If you don't have a good grasp of reflection, then my solution probably won't help too much.

Comment: Your idea and your concept is correct, maybe your syntax in c# is also correct(I did not test), but the syntax in vb.net is a little different. 
Finally I managed to convert your idea to a working vb.net code
Dim field_name = "NA"
dim query = from t in db.table.AsEnumurable.where(function(f) f.gettype.getproperty(field_name).GetValue(f,nothing) > 0) select t

I don't know why I had to add AsEnumurable in vb.net so that to work. Thanks a lot for your explanation and sorry it took that long time from me to get it.